# biblatex and tabular patching: error message

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, memoir, tabularx

```
(/localhost/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/localhost/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
(./TikZ-commands.tex)
(/localhost/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/australian.lbx
(/localhost/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/british.lbx
(/localhost/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)))

! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'tabularx' failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

                                                   l.251 \begin{document}
                       ? H This is an internal issue typically caused by a conflict between biblatex and some other package. Modifying the package loading order may fix the problem. ?
```

I get the above error message when I compile a book manuscript using the `memoir` class and many packages under XeLaTeX.

If I press on, I am able to compile the document but wish to remove the cause of this error.

I do not explicitly use the `tabularx` package but do use `longtable`.

I am able to supply more details but cannot make a minimal example just yet. I ma using TeXLive 2011 updated today and the vintage of `biblatex.sty` is

```
$Id: biblatex.sty,v 1.6 2011/07/29 19:21:28 lehman stable $  programmable bibliographies
```

EDIT: Sorry for not originally including the MWE; here it is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=none,language=australian,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example for the bug reported at \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30148/biblatex-and-tabular-patching-error-message}.
\end{document}
```

I get the same error message as reported above.

Comment: I think you really need to provide more information. Otherwise it's too hard to figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: @chandra: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is an incompatibility between `biblatex` and the lastest version 6.82i of `hyperref`. By default (i.e., with the `hyperfootnotes` option enabled), `hyperref` will redefine the `tabularx`/`memoir` macro `\TX@endtabularx`. This in turn causes the `biblatex` redefinition of the same macro to fail and produce the observed error message. As a workaround, load `hyperref` with the option `hyperfootnotes=false`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=none,language=australian,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example for the bug reported at \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30148/biblatex-and-tabular-patching-error-message}.
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: This behaviour is fixed in `hyperref` 6.82j/`biblatex` 1.7.